# Does the size attribute in @page include the margin?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing, media

I have some CSS:

```
@page { 
   size: 8.5in 11in; 
   margin: 0.5in;
}
```

This seems to work fine in Chrome, but I am having printing issues in IE9 with extra blank pages being printed. I wonder if I should subtract the margins from the page size.